# python string formatting portion cut off

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm a total beginner and this is my first question so I know this is probably stupid. But in python when I try and format a string with this code:

```
x = 7
print "% how do you do" % (x)
```

I get this as a result:

```
7w do you do
```

Is there a reason why the "ho" in "how" is getting cut off?

Comment: use `%d` ................

Comment: `%ho` stands for `unsigned short int` as octal, which is why it is replaced by the number

Answer (score 0):

Probably using %d instead of % will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Best solution here is to use `format` function.

```
>>> '{0} is bigger than {1}'.format('elephant', 'dog')
'elephant is bigger than dog
```

You can read more about formatting in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-examples)